# How to create a histogram of a matrix?

Tags: r

Can you please help me create a histogram of the matrix below,  using rnorm and hist functions?

Also can you please help me answer the following questions?

1. Assume these were results of a survey about the flavor of a new brand of carrot juice, being 1, Not satisfied at all, and 4 Very satisfied AND determine if there are values larger than 4
2. Create a histogram of the total data matrix
3. Create a histogram of one state that you like, AND determine if it is different than the histogram of the total data matrix

```r
m1 <-matrix(sample(x = 1:4, size = 35*15, replace = TRUE), nrow = 35, ncol = 15)
m1

getwd()
write.table(m1, file = "mymatrix.txt", sep = "\t", 
            col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE)
dir()
rm(m1)
dir()
m1
m1imported <- read.table(file = "mymatrix.txt", sep = "\t", 
                         header = TRUE, row.names = 1) # read any file
m1imported

us<-c("CALIFORNIA", "FLORIDA", "ARIZONA", "MICHIGAN", 
      "WASHINGTON", "GEORGIA", "TEXAS", "OHIO", "ALABAMA",
      "COLORADO","NEW JERSEY","VIRGINIA","MONTANA","OREGON","NEW YORK")

colnames (m1imported) = us
m1imported

num <- c(1:35)
rownames (m1imported) = num
m1imported

#I tried the following to create the histogram but gave me an error 
# Error in hist.default(m1imported) : 'x' must be numeric

hist(m1imported)
```

Comment: `read.table` reads in as a data frame, try `hist(as.matrix(m1imported))` or `hist(unlist(m1imported))`, and `hist(m1imported$CALIFORNIA)`. And _please_ [format your code on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Thank you and sorry , just started using this website 2 days ago.  I am a noob at this.  What about " determine if it is different than the histogram of the total data matrix"?  Can we compare the histograms?